# How to group array based on common value?

Tags: javascript

I have data structure like below:

```
a : { active: true, key: "first", page: 1 },
b : { active: true, key: "second", page: 1 },
c : { active: true, key: "third", page: 2 },
d : { active: true , key: "fourth", page: 2 },
e : { active: false , key: "fifth", page: 3 },
```

From this data, first I need to find data with active status true then I need to create a new array containing sub array with same page number. I need something like this.

```
[
    ["first", "second"],
    ["third", "fourth"],
    ["fifth"]
]
```

What I have tried is:

```
let myArray = Object.entries(dashboardKeyConfiguration).filter(x => x[1]["active"]);

var groups = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var groupName = myArray[i][1]["page"];
            if (!groups[groupName]) {
                groups[groupName] = [];
            }
            groups[groupName].push(myArray[i][1]["key"]);
        }
        myArray = [];
        console.log(groups);
```

It is inserting empty as first item like this:

```
(3) [empty, Array(2), Array(2)]
```

Comment: 1) You're filtering out items that are not active, so why should `"fifth"` be included? 2) When I run the code, I see `[null,["first","second"],["third","fourth"]]`. Most likely you just need to subtract 1 from `groupName` (because array indexes start at zero).

Comment: Why you need `"fifth"` in result. Its `acitve` is `false`

Comment: Sorry,  I dont need fifth. i need only 4 based on above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `page` starts from `1` Just subtract `1` from `groupName`

```js
let obj = { a : { active: true, key: "first", page: 1 }, b : { active: true, key: "second", page: 1 }, c : { active: false, key: "third", page: 2 }, d : { active: false , key: "fourth", page: 2 }, e : { active: true , key: "fifth", page: 3 }} 


let myArray = Object.entries(obj).filter(x => x[1]["active"]);
var groups = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var groupName = myArray[i][1]["page"]-1;
            if (!groups[groupName]) {
                groups[groupName] = [];
            }
            groups[groupName].push(myArray[i][1]["key"]);
        }
groups = groups.filter(x => x !== undefined)
console.log(groups)
```

Comment: let obj = {
a : { active: true, key: "first", page: 1 },
b : { active: true, key: "second", page: 1 },
c : { active: false, key: "third", page: 2 },
d : { active: false , key: "fourth", page: 2 },
e : { active: true , key: "fifth", page: 3 }} when my data is like this it gives empty again'

Comment: That is because this time `page:2` is excluded

Comment: You can `filter()` `undefined ` in the end. I have edited

Comment: i still have empty in the middle

Comment: Its giving `[
  [
    "first",
    "second"
  ],
  [
    "fifth"
  ]
]` in my console. Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: @user1687891 You can try `groups = groups.filter(x => Boolean(x))` in the end

Comment: Yes thank you i think i missed something from your code .. i fixed

Answer (score 2):

What we can to is define the `pageLength` max number of pages we can have. Then we can loop from i to `pageLength` and search the object for the page and push it in the temp array. Once loop completes for a specific page push the temp `array` in the main `array`

```js
const obj = {
        a : { active: true, key: "first", page: 1 },
        b : { active: true, key: "second", page: 1 },
        c : { active: true, key: "third", page: 2 },
        d : { active: true , key: "fourth", page: 2 },
        e : { active: false , key: "fifth", page: 3 },
        }
        let pageLength = 3;
        let array = [] ;
        
        for(let i = 1;i<=pageLength;i++){  
            temp = [];   
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    let value = obj[key].key;
                    let page = obj[key].page;
                    if(page == i){    
                        temp.push(value);
                    } 
                }
            }
            array.push(temp) 
        }
        
        console.log(array)
```

**It is just a raw logic. Keep in mind that the complexity for this can might be high and you could do it in a better way.**

Comment: if you want to check for status you can also do this 
let active = obj[key].active
if(page == i && active==true)

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.values(Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key)=>{
    if(obj[key].active) {if(acc[obj[key].page]) {acc[obj[key].page].push(obj[key].key)} else {acc[obj[key].page] = [obj[key].key]}}
        return acc
},{}))
```

We can reduce the object entries where the "active key is true" to an object

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key)=>{
     if(obj[key].active) {if(acc[obj[key].page]) {acc[obj[key].page].push(obj[key].key)} else {acc[obj[key].page] = [obj[key].key]}}
        return acc
},{})

output:
{
    1:["first","second"],
    3:["fifth"]
}
```

We can take the values from this object

```
[["first","second"],["fifth"]]
```

For more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Please provide some description along with code so that other people can easily understand your answer